# Passing Javascript Global Variable into PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm having problems passing a js global variable to PHP so I can query my DB for more data. I set the js variable on click of a link that loads a modal. In this example the variable is 'id3'. I need to pass that into php so I can include it in my where statement. Thanks!

JavaScript:

```
<script>
$("#cluster_profiles_dataTables").on("click", "a", function() {
   id3 = $(this).attr('id');
   document.querySelector('#clusterprofiletitlepulse').innerHTML = '<h4 class="modal-title" id="pulse">Profile Status' + ' (' + id3 + ')</h4>';
   document.querySelector('#clusterprofilepulsetable').innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i> '+ id3 + ' Additional Anomalies';
    $('#cluster_profile_pulse_table').dataTable( {
     "sAjaxSource": "../scripts/cluster_profile_pulse_table.php?val=" + id3,
});

}); 
$('#clusterprofileanomalies').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
   $('#cluster_profile_pulse_table').dataTable().fnDestroy();
 });
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id3'])) $id3 = $_GET['id3'];
$sql = "SELECT PROFILE_ATTACHED FROM <databasehidden> WHERE CLUSTER_NAME = '".$id3."'";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
    if( $stmt === false) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
    }

    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    echo'<tr class="'.$class.'">
    <center>'.$row['PROFILE_ATTACHED'].'</center>
    </tr>';
    }

?>
```

Comment: You have to use `$_GET['val']`. `

Comment: This looks [terrifyingly insecure](http://bobby-tables.com/). Are you **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php)?

Comment: `<center>` isn't a valid child of `<tr>`..in fact it is a deprecated tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your ajax source is:

```
 "sAjaxSource": "../scripts/cluster_profile_pulse_table.php?val=" + id3,
```

the id3 is stored in val ( val=id3). So
You must use this code to get the value:

```
if (isset($_GET['val'])) $id3 = $_GET['val'];
```

Comment: While this snippet might fix the issue, it would be nice to describe your approach so that future readers, having a different but similar issue, benefit from it.

Comment: @RandomSeed Thanx for your advice. I added some explanation. Is it sufficient??

Answer (score -2):

you must write your the variable in this mode:

var id3 = $(this).attr('id');

Marco

Comment: When you do that you do not have a global variable anymore. If `var` is not declared the property will be added to the `window` object.